# Showing plots if checkbox is checked, on python (with PyQt4)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I'm brand new to Python and I'm trying to make my first program with PyQt4. My problem is basically the following: I have two checkboxes (Plot1 and Plot2), and a "End" push button, inside my class. When I press End, I would like to see only the plots that the user checks, using matplotlib. I'm not being able to do that. My first idea was:

```
        self.endButton.clicked.connect(self.PlotandEnd)
        self.plot1Checkbox.clicked.connect(self.Plot1)
        self.plot2Checkbox.clicked.conncet(self.Plot2)

    def PlotandEnd(self)
        plot1=self.Plot1()
        pyplot.show(plot1)
        plot2=self.Plot2()
        pyplot.show(plot2)

    def Plot1(self)
        plot1=pyplot.pie([1,2,5,3,2])
        return plot1

    def Plot2(self)
        plot2=pyplot.plot([5,3,5,8,2])
        return plot2
```

This doesn't work, of course, because "PlotandEnd" will plot both figures, regardless of the respective checkbox. How can I do what I'm trying to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the plot creation in an if statement that looks at the state of the check boxes. For example:

```
def PlotandEnd(self)
    if self.plot1Checkbox.isChecked():
        plot1=self.Plot1()
        pyplot.show(plot1)

    if self.plot2Checkbox.isChecked():
        plot2=self.Plot2()
        pyplot.show(plot2)
```

You also **don't** need the following lines:

```
    self.plot1Checkbox.clicked.connect(self.Plot1)
    self.plot2Checkbox.clicked.conncet(self.Plot2)
```

This does nothing useful at the moment! Qt never uses the return value of your `PlotX()` methods, and you only want things to happen when you click the End button, not when you click a checkbox. The `PlotX()` methods are only currently useful for your `PlotandEnd()` method.

Comment: @Thiagogps93 If this answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as the "accepted answer" by clicking on the tick mark to the left of it and/or upvoting the answer.

Comment: I made in the accepted answer. I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet, though.